# C++ Queues, Run-Time Failure Check #2 MAX_QUEUE_SIZE

Tags: c++, runtime

I'm still new to C++ and I'm not sure how to fix this error. What I need the code to do is create a queue that takes user input, however if they put in more than 10 inputs then they should receive an error message.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

const int MAX_QUE_SIZE = 10;

class QueueOverFlowException {
public:
 QueueOverFlowException() {
    cout << "QUEUE OVERFLOW" << endl;
 }
};

class QueueEmptyException {
public:
  QueueEmptyException()
{
    cout << "EMPTY QUEUE" << endl;
 }
};

class queue {
private:
 int data[MAX_QUE_SIZE];
 int front;
 int rear;

public:
 queue() {
    front = -1;
    rear = -1;
}

void enqueue(int element) {
     if (queuesize() == MAX_QUE_SIZE - 1)
        throw new QueueOverFlowException();

    data[rear] = element;
    rear = ++rear % MAX_QUE_SIZE;
}

int dequeue() {
    if (isEmpty())
        throw new QueueEmptyException();

    int i = data[front];
    front = ++front % MAX_QUE_SIZE;

    return i;
}

int queuefront() {
    if (isEmpty())
        throw new QueueEmptyException();

    return data[front];
}

int queuesize() {
    return abs(rear - front);
}

bool isEmpty() {
    return (front == rear) ? true : false;
 }
};

int main(){
 queue q;

int i;
std::cout << "Please enter some integers (enter 0 to exit):\n";

do {
    std::cin >> i;
    q.enqueue(i);
} while (i != 0);

std::cout << endl;
return 0;
}
```

The Run-Time error says the variable q in int main is corrupted but only when the user enters a zero.

Comment: Can you give us the input that causes the runtime error?  Additionally can you tell us what compiler you are using?  

I just compiled your example with g++ version 4.8.4 and was able to run the code with the expected results (e.g. an exception thrown when entering [1-10] and normal program completion when entering [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,0]